# .htaccess, two rules for one file, white page

Tags: .htaccess

this is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?u=$1&c=$2 [L]
```

it doesn't work if I don't have the second argument, c=something. like mydomain.com/something = white page, mydomain.com/something/again works. What can I do to make only first argument work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1&c=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- `RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`.
- Better to use `L` flag after each rule.